# useradd --prefix option

Tags: useradd

If I'm not mistaken, the `--prefix` option of `useradd` should allow me to change the etc files from the directory I select, but it strangely adds an extra `/`.

I'm using Linux Mint 21.1 mate 64bit version if anybody asks.

The entire command I execute is this one:

```
useradd -R /home/user/fakeroot -P  /home/user/Desktop newuser
```

And this is the output I get

```
useradd: /home/user/Desktop//etc/passwd.37507: No such file or directory
useradd: cannot lock /home/user/Desktop//etc/passwd; try again later.
```

How can I get rid of that extra `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra `/` is irrelevant. Consecutive `/` are collapsed into a single one with no error message and no problem. For instance:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon
$ cd ///////////////etc
$ pwd
/etc
$ cd //////usr/////local//////bin
$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
```

Now, the `-P` option of `adduser` is:

> -P, --prefix PREFIX_DIR
>
> Apply changes to configuration files under the root filesystem found under
> the directory PREFIX_DIR. This option does not chroot and is intended for
> preparing a cross-compilation target. Some limitations: NIS and LDAP
> users/groups are not verified. PAM authentication is using the host files. No
> SELINUX support.

But the `-R` option is:

> -R, --root CHROOT_DIR
>
> Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the configuration files
> from the CHROOT_DIR directory. Only absolute paths are supported.

I suspect that it doesn't make sense to use both of them, they basically do the same thing in a different way. I don't know the details here, and I may be wrong, but based on your output, it looks like the `-P` is overwriting the `-R`. Very probably, both options set the same variable in `adduser`'s code, and the one you gave last overwrites the previous one.

Presumably, you have a valid chroot environment set up under `/home/user/fakeroot`, but because of the `-P  /home/user/Desktop` you aren't using it and `adduser` is looking for `/home/user/Desktop/etc` instead of `/home/user/fakeroot/etc`.

I think you only want to use one of those two options and not both. If you explain what you are really trying to achieve, what the end result you're looking for is, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I'm trying to do is see if can manage the users of a chroot environment using etc files outside it

Comment: @mrdaemon oh, no, you can't. That's the whole point of a chroot environment, also know as a chroot _jail_, you don't have access to anything outside it.

Comment: OTOH, if `-R` does a `chroot()` (for whatever reason), I suppose it might be possible that `-P` would just work after it. I.e. `useradd -R /foo -P /bar` would make changes in (the global) `/foo/bar/etc/passwd`. But I'm really just guessing, and the combination would likely be of a rather niche use.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know either @ilkkachu, but based on what the OP shows, it looks like both `-R` and `-P` work in the same way, possiblhy setting the same variable in the code so that one overwrites the other.